# Jquery modal popup return to view and show summary message after comfirmation

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I have a modal popup just for comfirmation. When 'continue' is clicked it closes and it goes to the controller Action Delete and it returns. But after returning back to the view, the summary message validation div is not being showed which is what I want.

Here is the modal with div code:

```
<div id="delete-dialog" title="Confirmation">
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this?</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    //$(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
            var deleteLinkObj;


            $('.delete-link').click(function () {
                deleteLinkObj = $(this);  //for future use
                $('#delete-dialog').dialog('open');

                return false; // prevents the default behaviour
            });

            $('#delete-dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                height: 250,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true, //Dialog options

                buttons: {
                    "Continue": function () {
                        $.post(deleteLinkObj[0].href, function (data)
                        {  //Post to action
                            if (data == '')
                            {

                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }

                        });

                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function ()
                    {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    //})
</script>
```

So what i basically want it to do, is going to the controller if 'continue' is clicked, and show the summary message.

So how can I 'stop' the execution of the jquery function after comming from the controller?

I got the modal code from [this](http://ricardocovo.com/2010/09/02/asp-mvc-delete-confirmation-with-ajax-jquery-ui-dialog/) site

Comment: What is that you are returning from your controller to jQuery when you click `Continue`

Comment: I mean what does `data` in $.post contains after returning from controller ?

Comment: It contains a whole html page. The controller returns a result which is a summary validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) of `jQuery` inside your callback, after the post.

As you did not show any div. I'm assuming the div as

```
<div id="summary"></div>
```

This is how you the final dialog is :

```
$('#delete-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        height: 250,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true, //Dialog options

        buttons: {
            "Continue": function () {
                $.post(deleteLinkObj[0].href, function (data)
                {  //Post to action
                    if (data == '')
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#summary').append(data); // this will append the content in data to your div with id as summary
                    }

                });

                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function ()
            {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I found another modal dialog code after hours of search. and it kinda matched yours. marked as answered, thanks!